# Embed a YouTube video with 9:16 ratio full width and full height - iframe api

Tags: html, css, iframe, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I want to embed a youtube video on 9:16 ratio on a mobile app( Flutter - inAppWebView plugin) using iframe api. I've sucessfully embeded the youtube video on 16:9 ratio but I want to cover my video entire height and width of the mobile in potrait mode(9:16) like in tik-tok video app feed.

I've tried many css tricks but ended up something awful. Is there any css tricks that'll help with my case. I want my output video to be exactly like the below image.

[Link: Video output to be expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MysSE.jpg)

Here's my iframe code,

```
<iframe class="video" id="player"  type="text/html" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/qHFCMgLhp9s" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
.video {
     aspect-ratio : 16/9
}
```